# ¿Les ha dejado de fucionar el navegador de anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Desde hace un par de días he estado teniendo un problema con anaconda. No corre el navegador. Lo lanzo desde el inicio, desde el escritorio, incluso directamente el pythonw.exe dentro del path donde está instalado. La primera vez que me pasó desinstalé y volví a instalar, pero ya me volvió a suceder y no quisiera tener que desinstalar e instalar todos los días. Al darle doble click ni siquiera registra el procesos en el administrador de proceso. Estoy usando windows 11.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la colaboración.

Comment: En MacOS y Windows 10 no he tenido problemas, en Windows 11 no te podria decir aunque no necesariamente el sistema operativo pueda ser el problema. ;)

Comment: Ejecuta el exe directamente en la consola, es muy posible que te muestre la fuente del error (o alguna pista al menos) que esta impidiendo su correcta ejecución.